# Weird React problem with axios and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my problem is about nested axios request. The code is very simple, with first axios.get i am fetching first portion of data and then using the given respons I am trying to fetch data from second endpoint. (code below)

```
const getData = async () => {
let returnSecoundValue = {}

try {
  const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/firstEndpoint/", {
    auth: {
      username: "x",
      password: "y",
    },
  });
  // console.log(response.data) <--- WORKS;

  response.data.forEach(async element => {
    const secoundData = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/secoundEndpoint/${element.id}/`, {
      auth: {
        username: "x",
        password: "y",
      },
    });

    returnSecoundValue[secoundData.data.id] = secoundData.data
  });
  console.log(returnSecoundValue) <--- WORKS;
  setMyState({firstEnd: response.data, secoundEnd: empoRet})
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

As in example above when I am finished fetching second data, I save it in my state as an object. The First element of an object is an array of objects, and the second is the object (used as disc).

Up to this point everything is fine, when I try and console.log it, it shows perfectly as I wanted. Problem starts when I'am trying to get the exact data from the second element.

With my fetched data I'am trying to do something like that:

```
myState.firstEnd.map((element) => {
              try{
              console.log(myState); (Works - log all values)
              console.log(myState.secoundEnd); (Works - log all values of secoundEnd)
              console.log(myState.secoundEnd[2]); (Return undefind)

                    <Component
                        key={element.id}
                        isActive={element.active}
                        title={element.title}
```

I have tried to do that in few approaches but each time I ended up with the same result. Is there a problem with mounting or is it something else?

Comment: you aren't awaiting your inner calls. you have to use `.map` and `Promise.all`

Comment: no there are no problems in mounting make sure your "secondEnd" has the index 2.

Comment: `console.log(returnSecoundValue) <--- WORKS;` It's not really working, you're just running into a quirk of console.log. The browser does not evaluate the object when the log statement runs, it evaluates it when you click to view it in the console. So at the time of the log statement, the object is empty. Then you do some async work, and mutate the object. Then you click in the log and see those changes you made. Change the line to `console.log(JSON.stringify(returnSecoundValue))` and you'll see that it's an empty object.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank u, i change up my code and now everything works.

Comment: @NicholasTower Thank, u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I figured out the problem.
This is the solution:

```
const secoundValue = response.data.map(async element => {
 await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/secoundEndpoint/${element.id}/`, 
 {
   auth: {
     username: "x",
     password: "y",
   },
 });
});

  Promise.all(secoundValue).then((res) => {
    res.map((e)=>{
      secoundEnd[e.data.id] = e.data
    })  

    setMyState({ ads: resp.data, emp: empoRet });
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).